# Is question on replacement of library off-topic or not?

Tags: discussion, scope

Some programming library has been deprecated some time ago. My question is,

Asking to replacement of the deprecated library is off-topic?

I am not sure this question type is an example of

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

And I see some questions, like [What's the best alternative library to gettimeofday() in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2198239/1539100), that explicitly request an alternative library from a non-deprecated (*more* general than my question type) library and get voted up.

Comment: "What's the best library for X" seems to also cover "What's the best library for replacing library Y". So these seem to be clearly off-topic today. Do you have a reason beside an ancient question to assume otherwise?

Comment: Yes, it is bit similar, but my question is specific in deprecated library. in this situation, user does not two options and try to compression between them, user could not use library Y, and ask the community to provide alternative method.

Comment: Anyway, if you think it's off topic, where should these questions be asked?

Comment: I don't see how replacing a specific library makes this any more on-topic. The decisive feature is how many possible recommendations there are, and even for replacing one specific library there may be dozens or more with more coming up as time goes on. Unless there clearly is *a* standard library replaced by *a* new standard library, there very likely will be many options.

Comment: Just FYI, [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) also allow programming libraries.

Comment: Tagging "?" to the end of a statement does not make it [a question](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4yWEt0OSpg&t=1m49s).

Comment: Ask how to solve a problem. Don't ask for a library. Using a library can, of course, sometimes be the solution to a problem.

Comment: *"That explicitly request an alternative library from a non-deprecated (more general than my question type) library and get voted up."* - it seems like a decently asked question, so why not? Whether something is on-topic or not and whether it is of decent quality or not are two entirely different and unrelated layers of quality control that the site has. One controlled by a close vote, the other by a quality vote. One is not an argument for or against the other.

Answer (score 16):

The question you referenced shows exactly the problem why these type of questions are off-topic.
A decent looking question with some code that asks: *What's the best alternative library to gettimeofday() in C++* where several answers offer altenatives, some get dismissed by the OP because they have requirements that they didn't bother to mention in the question.
In the end it turns out their problem didn't even need a library.

This is how you might ask for a replacement of a library:

> I current call Foo from DoomedLib to FrobTheBaz. As DoomedLib is deprecated I switched to PromisingLib as that allows me the FrobTheBaz as well. However calling Fuz doesn't FrobTheBaz instead it barks at me. How can I FrobTheBaz with PromisingLib? I'm not committed to PromisingLib. If there are other options that achieves the same, I'm happy to consider those.

That last sentence is basically your invite for an off-site recommendation. Note that you have to do some upfront work to find at least one reasonable alternative that brings you close to meet your requirement. From there you can offload the short-list creation and/or solving of the issue at hand to the community.

It can be tempting to ask on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) but remember that they also expect you to do work before hand. Their Help says:

> Good software recommendation requests have two components:
>
> - A purpose — a task to accomplish, a user story
> - Some objective requirements — a minimum set of features

Specially that last bit is often overlooked. So much that they have meta post about it: https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336

Comment: Nitpick: The original question contained the assertion *"there are no Boost libraries"*. Thus, it *was* clear from the outset that the asker of the question was not willing to use Boost. Merits of that decision aside, this wasn't a case of moving the goalposts or even an unclear/underspecified question. So it doesn't really epitomize the issue with recommendation-style questions. It more epitomizes the issue of people not reading the question in full. Or at least the problem with questions that have unusual and unexpected requirements.